# Detecting interaction with browser UI within Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari

Is anyone aware of a way with JS to detect interaction with the native UI in mobile Safari. An example event would be a click on the URL bar or the bookmarks icon. I'd like to be able to trigger a change on the page with JS on these events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JavaScript does not have access to these events. You would need to use a plug-in.

Your best hope is to detect the mouse leaving the browser pane.

Comment: My assumption is that you're correct - but I was/am hoping that a mobile safari would have a native API for events like this. Obviously mouse events aren't relevant in the mobile space.

Comment: It does, just not through JavaScript.